# How to link my QGIS plugin main class to mouse events from a custom Tool?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I want to execute the `merge(self,aLayer)` method after clicking with the tool I've created, i.e. after the mouse click I want the control to come to the `main.py` module how can I do that using Python programming?

I have two files one is `mouseevent.py` and the other one `main.py`.

```
class MouseClick(QgsMapTool):
    canvasDoubleClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, object)

    def __init__(self, canvas,layer,Vertex_list,mergeDlg):
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.layer=layer
        self.Vertex_list=Vertex_list
        self.mergeDlg=mergeDlg
        self.rb = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QGis.Line)
        self.rb.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        self.rb.setWidth(2)
        self.rb.reset()
    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):

        if event.button() == 1:
            print "helo"
            x = event.pos().x()
            y = event.pos().y()
            Lpoint = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)
            print 'Then Left points are',Lpoint


    def canvasMoveEvent(self, event):
        pass

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        #Get the click
        if event.button() == 2:
            print "hello right"
            x = event.pos().x()
            y = event.pos().y()
            Rpoint = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)
            print 'Then Right points are',Rpoint
            self.Vertex_list.append(Rpoint)
            print 'The list after right click is',self.Vertex_list

    def canvasSelectionChanged(self,layer):

        pass
    def activate(self):
        pass

    def deactivate(self):
        pass

    def isZoomTool(self):
        return False

    def isTransient(self):
        return False

    def isEditTool(self):
        return True
```

Main.py:

```
def merge(self,aLayer):
    canvas=qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
    aLayer=canvas.currentLayer()
    aLayer.removeSelection()
    selection=aLayer.selectedFeatures()
    print 'length is',len(selection)


def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    mergeDlg = MergeDialog()
    Vertex_list = []
    global Vertex_list
    MergeByFreeHand.readConfigfile(self)
    AreaList=[]
    Value=99
    canvas=qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
    aLayer=canvas.currentLayer()
    aLayer.removeSelection()
    qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(aLayer)
    count=0
    global count          
    tool = MouseClick(canvas,aLayer,Vertex_list,mergeDlg,count)
    qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
```

Comment: You should look into signals and slots in PyQt.

Comment: I have tried (QObject.connect(tool, SIGNAL("triggered()"),self.merge)) that but not wrking for me can you suggest me any code?

Comment: I am just teaching myself all this, so it is hard for me to fix this code. But there are some other users here who are really good at PyQGIS. I think that within an hour you should have an answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use PyQt4 SIGNALS/SLOTS for that. The reference documentation is [this one](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html).

SIGNALS/SLOTS allow you to keep components isolated in your application while providing you with a way to communicate among them, which is your case.

In your example, do the following steps:

1. First of all, you don't need to pass the parameter `aLayer` to your `merge()` method, do you? So, just leave `def merge(self):` while defining the method.
2. You need to define a custom SIGNAL to inform other components when a click has been done using your tool. This way:

   a. Set a new pyqtSignal() object in your `MouseClick` class:

   ```
   class MouseClick(QgsMapTool):
       afterClick = pyqtSignal()
       ...
   ```

   b. Emit the `afterClick` signal after your code in the release event (or place it wherever you want, it depends on your needs):

   ```
   def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
       #Get the click
       if event.button() == 2:
          # Your "if" code goes here
       self.afterClick.emit()
   ```
3. In your `run()` function, after creating the `tool` object, connect its `afterClick` signal to your `merge()` method, this way:

   ```
   tool = MouseClick(canvas,aLayer,Vertex_list,mergeDlg,count)
   tool.afterClick.connect(self.merge)
   qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
   ```

Comment: It is working perfectly fine.Thank you.. But i want this process to move from Mouseevent.py to Main.py and main.py to Mouseevent.py until i break the loop how can i do that? Bec if i click on the plugin the process is happening only once if i want o execute again i have to click on the plugin to avoid that how can i do?

Comment: Isn't the tool still active on the map after `merge()` runs?

Comment: Yes it is not active so i am calling the tool in the if condition again so the tool is active now.That problem is solved. But when i am pressing the ESCAPE button it has to make the tool deactivate.How can i do that using python programming?  I have used event.ignore() but it is nt working so is there any way to close the event.